# Java add element with attributes to xml file

Tags: java, xml, file, fullcalendar

Hello fellow programmers :).

I'm very new to Java and if this was PHP i already have done this :P, anyway i tried to search all answers in here (stackoverflow) but none fits my specific problem, or i haven´t seen an example or i missed something...anyway please post links to answers if you know any solution similar to my problem.

Ok to the problem ;)

I have this XML in a file, and i need it to be just like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
    <event id="46" title="Ferias" start="2013-04-25" end="2013-04-26" allDay="false" editable="true"/>
    <event id="47" title="Falta" start="Wed Apr 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" end="Thu Apr 18 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" allDay="false" editable="true"/>
    <event id="48" title="Tolerancia de Ponto" start="Mon Apr 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" end="" allDay="false" editable="true"/>    
    <event id="49" title="Titulo teste" start="Thu Apr 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" end="Sat Apr 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" allDay="true" editable="true"/>
    <event id="50" title="dfgfdgf" start="Fri Apr 12 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" end="Sat Apr 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" allDay="true" editable="true"/>
    <event id="51" title="hghfjfghj" start="Tue Apr 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" end="Wed Apr 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" allDay="true" editable="true"/>
    <event id="52" title="grande evento" start="Tue Apr 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" end="Wed May 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100" allDay="true" editable="true"/>
</events>
```

and i'm trying to add a new element "event" with atributes and i'm using this to load and modify:

```
        String FilePath = "D:/myxml.xml";
    Document doc = openXMLfile(FilePath);
```

its loaded no problem here..

where openXMLfile is this:

```
protected Document openXMLfile(String filepath){
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File(filepath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

then in my function to add element i do this:

```
File file = new File("D:\myxml.xml");
Element event = doc.createElement("event");
    event.setAttribute("test","testvalue");
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(event);

    filePutContents(doc,file);
```

where filePutContents i have this function:

```
protected void filePutContents(Document doc,File file){
    try{                    
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();    
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);//problem was this
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);//correct way
                transformer.transform(source, result);

    }catch(TransformerConfigurationException tce){
        /*ERRO do Transformer*/         
        System.out.println("* Transformer Factory error");
        System.out.println(" " + tce.getMessage());

        Throwable x = tce;
        if (tce.getException() != null)
            x = tce.getException();
            x.printStackTrace(); 
    }catch(TransformerException te){
        /*ERRO da Factory*/
        System.out.println("* Transformation error");
        System.out.println(" " + te.getMessage());

        Throwable x = te;
        if (te.getException() != null)
            x = te.getException();
            x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, no element is added to the file,i want the file to be updated, what am i doing wrong? Thank you

Problem solved, i have reflected changes in code ;) thank to do helpers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
```

The above statement is directing your output to the console (System.out). Point it to the file if you want file to be updated.

Try this-

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("somefile.xml"));
```

Comment: i have tried :
File file = new File(filepath);

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);

and

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(file));

btw this must be in try catch

didnt work :(

Comment: Ok thats it i was doing things wrong:

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);

Works fine thanks ;)